# Fetching data from core data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am using following code to fetch data from core database. But when I am pushing another view controller on current view and change some text on any text field and click cancel button without saving/updating text into DB.After clicking on cancel button I pop this view controller and then this method call again from viewDidApear method and then that edited text is come from following method. But I didn't save/update that text into database.

```
-(Notes *)fetchSpecificNoteWithNoteID:(NSString* )noteID 
    {

        NSEntityDescription *roomObj = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes"
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext]];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notesID=%@",noteID];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        [request setEntity:roomObj];
        NSArray *array = [[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if ([array count] && array) {
            return [array objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented any delegate method of textfield? If yes then can u show us what code have you written in those method..

Comment: what exactly you are doing on cancel button ! only pop viewController or anyThing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to managed objects are automatically 'saved' in the context. The only manual saving you need to do is to write it to the backing store.

Somewhere you set the new value on the managed object. If you want to cancel this, you need to roll back the changes in some way.